# FindDistributionParameters of a sum of a mixture distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have this Mixture Distribution of two Normal Distributions:

```
 mix[p_, μ1_, μ2_, σ_] := 
 MixtureDistribution[{p, 
 1 - p}, {NormalDistribution[μ1, σ], 
 NormalDistribution[μ2, σ]}];
```

Say $x_1, x_2$ are samples from this mixture. Set $y=x_1+x_2$, so that $y$ is the sum of two samples from the mixture.
I now generate 100 $y's$ (with arbitrary p, mu and sigma, each is a sum of two $x$:

```
mixdat = RandomVariate[mix[0.75, 0.5, -1.5, 0.2], 1000];
mixdatSum = 
Total[RandomVariate[mix[0.75, 0.5, -1.5, 0.2], 2]] & /@ Range[100];
```

mixdatSum contains these 100 values.
Now given the data in mixdatSum I want to estimate the Distribution Parameters.
So a natural way to solve this would be:

```
FindDistributionParameters[mixdatSum, 
TransformedDistribution[x1 + x2, 
Thread[Distributed[{x1, x2}, 
MixtureDistribution[{p, 
  1 - p}, {NormalDistribution[μ1, σ], 
  NormalDistribution[μ2, σ]}]]]]]
```

Problem is, the sum of a mixture does not follow the mixture distribution, so this does not work and I get lots of errors.

However I want to treat the sum of a mixture AS IF IT WERE following the same mixture, for approximation purposes.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `PDF` can be computed in closed form you might have some luck with `ProbabilityDistribution` and some half-way reasonable starting values.

Generate the data...

```
mix[p_, m1_, m2_, s_] := MixtureDistribution[{p, 1 - p}, {NormalDistribution[m1, s], 
    NormalDistribution[m2, s]}];

mixdatSum = Plus @@ RandomVariate[mix[0.75, 0.5, -1.5, 0.2], {2, 100}];
```

Use your `TransformedDistribution` to get the `PDF`.

```
sumdist = TransformedDistribution[x1 + x2, Thread[Distributed[{x1, x2}, 
     MixtureDistribution[{p,  1 - p}, {NormalDistribution[m1, s], 
       NormalDistribution[m2, s]}]]]];

pdf[z_] = FullSimplify[PDF[sumdist, z], DistributionParameterAssumptions[sumdist]]
```

Create a `ProbabilityDistribution` from your `PDF` with the proper assumptions set.

```
pdist = ProbabilityDistribution[pdf[z], {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> DistributionParameterAssumptions[sumdist]]
```

With some starting values in the right ballpark you can get good estimates of the parameters.

```
FindDistributionParameters[mixdatSum, pdist, {{m1, 1}, {m2, -1}, {s, 1}, {p, .5}}]

(*{m1 -> 0.514195, m2 -> -1.53428, s -> 0.226609, p -> 0.719953}
```

Comment: thanks, this is looking great. Is there a way to get this to work with a Mixture Distribution of two LogNormal Distributions? There is no closed form there.

Comment: To my knowledge you won't have any luck with `ProbabilityDistribution` if you don't have a closed form for one of the distribution functions.

Comment: According to a paper I read the sum of two Lognormals is approximately Lognormal. Can I use this to define my own `ProbabilityDensity` for the sum of two Lognormals?